# How can I call an asynchronous method using the Geolocation API?

Tags: reactjs, async-await, fetch

In my React app I want to be able to call an API endpoint with the current location of the user using the [Geolocation API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API).

I have the following method which fires when a user clicks a button

```
findMeetings = async () => {

  const location = window.navigator && window.navigator.geolocation

  if (location) {
    location.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
    let url = `meetings/find?lat=${position.coords.latitude}&lng=${position.coords.longitude}&radius=${this.state.radius}`;
    let result = await fetch(`https://localhost:44303/api/${url}`, {
      method: 'get'
     }).then(response => response.json());
    this.setState({ meetings: result.meetings })
   }, (error) => {

  })
}
```

I get the following error:

> Parsing error: await is a reserved word

I think this is because I am calling an async method inside of `getCurrentPosition` - can anyone help me understand what the problem is here and how I can resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be because even though the parent method has the keyword async (findMeetings), the location.getCurrentPosition(..) function doesn't have an async keyword.

So trying something like this could help:

```
location.getCurrentPosition(async position => {
  .. actual code
})
```

Let me know if this works, cheers :)

Comment: Glad I could help!